# How to combine two for loops in Python3

Tags: python, for-loop

How to get the result as here in Python3 ?

```
---#
--##
-###
####
```

I want to combine two for loops. My code:

```
import sys

num_steps = int(sys.argv[1])
symb1 = "-"
symb2 = "#"

for i in range(num_steps + 1):
     print(symb2 * i)

for j in range(num_steps-1, 0, -1):
     print (symb1 * j)
```

Result :

```
#
##
###
####
---
--
-
```

Comment: You are doing a constant number of iterations per line you only need to decide when to switch the character you are printing.

Comment: Hint: try to calculate `j` given `i`

Comment: Answer: sǝɥsɐp (ʞ - sdǝʇs‾ɯnu) puɐ sǝɥsɐɥ (Ɩ + ʞ) sı ǝɹǝɥʇ ǝuıן ɥʇ-ʞ ɹoɟ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need two for loops - use a bit of math instead. As soon as you know how many characters you need for one symbol, you immediately know how many characters you need for the other symbol:

```
for i in range(1, num_steps + 1):
    print(symb1 * (num_steps - i) + symb2 * i)
```